# Models or images for things

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here is the context:

> Almost since the invention of writing, more than five thousand years ago, the signs that stood for words that expressed (or attempted to express) our thinking appeared to its users **as models or images for things** as intricate and aimless, as concrete or as abstract as the world in which we live and even life itself."
>
> From *The Traveler, The Tower and The Worm* by Alberto Manguel

What does "things" refer to? And would you please paraphrase the marked phrase?

Comment: Things are just things: what is being written about. More of a problem is what is *its* referring to? It can't be "our thinking" because that doesn't have users, and it can't be "the invention of writing" because that doesn't either. It could be "writing" but the sentence is unwieldy to the point of being gobbledygook.

Comment: Can you please paraphrase the sentence "appeared to its users as models or images for things as intricate and aimless, as concrete or as abstract as the world in which we live and even life itself."?

Comment: Objects / concepts.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Pretty sure the antecedent to *it* (if you mean in "appeared to its users"), yes, is "writing." And agreed; this sentence seems oddly adept at making almost the opposite point than it intends to. My paraphrase: "We live with, and think and talk about, *stuff*. All kinds of stuff. Abstract stuff, concrete stuff, stuff that is very detailed or that doesn't matter all that much. The images we make on clay or papyrus, that we call writing, is not this stuff, but we manage to associate these squiggles—these *symbols (models) and images* with the stuff of life."